# SQL: SELECT one post by category if no posts select from another category only one query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

**Purpose**:
Every half-hour I query database to find a post that havn't published to publish,every time I query by different category,if no posts in this category,switch to next category.
***The if check done by SQL***

**pseudo-code**

```
SELECT FROM post WHERE post.cat_ID='7' AND post_date > '$last_query_time_cat_ID_7' 
IF NO_POSTS_MATCH SELECT FROM post WHERE post.cat_ID='8' AND post_date>'$last_query_time_cat_ID_8'
...
```

**pseudo explain**:select one post of one category by its last query time of this category,if no new post of this category select from another category by its last query time.
**My question:**
Is there such SQL to do this work?
This can be done by php to check if no posts return,then make another sql query.This could make many queries.
Somebody show me the sql-pseudo-code of this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, do you want to get the latest (if there is one) unpublished post from each category?

Comment: @KristerAndersson latest is ok,the mainly question is: if no post in category A then select by category B then C,D,E... till find one post.

Comment: @home sorry,what do you mean?

Comment: @Sam4Ever: No prob, you've asked 9 (nine) questions and did not accept any answer. If you received helpful answers to one of your questions, please accept those. See the FAQ for further details.

Comment: @home Thanks,I just know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could look like this:

```sql
SELECT p.post_ID, p.cat_ID, p.post_date
FROM   post p
JOIN   (
    SELECT cat_ID
          ,max(query_time) AS last_query
    FROM   post 
    WHERE  cat_ID >= 7
    GROUP  BY 1
    ORDER  BY 1) l USING (cat_ID)
-- in some RDBMS you need ON l.cat_ID = p.cat_ID in the JOIN clause
WHERE  p.post_date > l.last_query
ORDER  BY p.cat_ID, p.post_date DESC
LIMIT  1;  -- In T-SQL you need to write "SELECT TOP 1" instead
```

#### Major points

- First get the timestamp of the last query per category in a subquery. We are only interested in `cat_ID >= 7`
- Join this to the base table and filter only rows with a later `post_date` than `last_query` per `cat_ID`.
- Sort it by `cat_ID` - you seem to want smallest `cat_ID` first. Secondary sort by `post_date` descending, so the last post comes first.
- If there are none in `cat_ID` 7, `cat_ID` 8 will be first etc. Voila.

Comment: **Thanks,great answer**,**one question**:different category has its own last_query_time,if use max(query_time),I think I will miss some posts.**example**:category A last_query_time=1,category B last_query_time=3,from time 1,2,3 I post to each A,B category,then I got 1A,1B,2A,2B,3A,3B posts,**result**:I think this query will only get 3A,3B?

Comment: @Sam4Ever: it is max(query_time) **per `cat_ID`**, you only get rows with `p.post_date > l.last_query`, so `2B` cannot be in the result of your example. On a different note: you haven't accepted or upvoted any answers yet. Have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: **input**:if I have post like:1A,2B,3A,and the A_last_query_time=1,B_last_query_time=1.**condition**:cat=A.**output**:3A. **condition**:cat=B.**output**:2B.**condition**:cat=C.**output**:3A or 2B.(no posts by cat C use A or B) I wish this example make sence.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CASE..WHEN...ELSE Statement.. See the link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html